# Mail server on 2 ISPs cannot receive outside mail

Tags: networking, email, router

I have been trying to fix this problem for a week now. My network has 2 ISP:

```
1: fixed IP -> Billion router -> mail and web servers
2: dynamic IP -> Linksys -> normal web browsing
```

They all used to work flawlessly until I reset the routers a week ago (following an advice by ISP to fix a problem). Until now I can make everything work except receiving mails from outside domains.

Billion - DHCP (192.168.2.1) is turned off. Virtual servers in NAT page set to corresponding server local IPs.

Linksys - DHCP (192.168.2.2) is set to relay to 192.168.2.101 (I don't know why. It was set by former admin who quits 2 months ago) Single Port Forwarding was set like before.

Here is the DNS setting in DNS-DIY:

```
(blank) - A - (global IP)
* - A - (global IP)
www - A - (global IP)
(blank) - MX - mail
mail - MX - (global IP)
```

Telnetting the local IP and mail.xxxx.com for 110 and 25 works, but xxxx.com doesn't.

Another thing I can tell is two routers are connected in some way. I don't know about details of the mail server. I am just a programmer and completely new to this network stuff. Even the network admin who quits 2 months ago cannot figure this out.

This issue is critical to the company I am working, so I need this fixed ASAP. I will provide any more information I can.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I just figured a way.

At first I changed all the DNS settings to Linksys (dynamic IP). E-mail works well but this is not a permanent solution.

The mail server appears to be Ubuntu OS of some kind. I searched for command lines on Google and found out its default gateway is 192.168.2.2

So I set it to 192.168.2.1 (fixed IP router) and now we can use the E-mail normally.

I don't know if there will be any more problems because of this change though.